# Zinc evaporation/toxicity at room temperature

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

I have a (slightly embarrassing) question regarding zinc powder.

I have recently broken an old mercury thermometer, and read that I can handle the mercury with powdered zinc - so I've sprinkled some on my floor. Too much probably. It turned out that unfortunately the powder is then quite hard to get out of the particular material of my floor (wood). I got out as much as possible, but I think there's still some left. So now I'm wondering if there is some danger if having all that zinc laying around.

Thanks anybody for the answer :)

Comment: If I were you, I'd be much more worried about mercury than about zinc.

Comment: @Peter Do you drive?  Zinc is all around you in your car's galvanized steel body panels.  I second Ivan's comment.

Comment: This isn't a personal medical question: it is a chemical safety question. And one that might be relevant to, for example, the best safety procedure in a lab. Which sounds like mainstream chemistry to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zinc will amalgamate with mercury, but whether that reduces the vapor pressure of mercury very much is debatable. At best, the increased volume of zinc amalgam and the ability to amalgamate with fine droplets of mercury would make it easier to clean up the mercury as amalgam.

It might be better to spread some sulfur dust (flowers of sulfur) over the area. The sulfur should react with the mercury and tie it up as sulfide, with very low vapor pressure. Sulfur powder (and possibly the HgS) might also be easier to clean up than zinc dust, because sulfur is more like ordinary dust than a dense metal dust.

BTW, I love mercury thermometers. And I hate it when I break them!